# Makefile: A dependency without a rule doesn't invalidate parent

Tags: c++, c, header-files, makefile

Here's a simplified version of my Makefile:

```
all: myprogram

myprogram: main.o
    c++ main.o -o myprogram

main.o: main.cpp mylib.hpp
    c++ -c main.cpp 

mylib.hpp: mylib.inl
```

All these files mentioned above are real files. When I change `mylib.hpp`, `main.cpp` recompiles. However, my problem is that when I change `mylib.inl`, main.cpp does *not* recompile. How can I invalidate the `main.o` target and therefore the `myprogram` target when I edit `mylib.inl`? I would prefer **not** to use a `.PHONY` target, because I don't want to recompile everything every time, just only when I edit `mylib.inl`.

Comment: Hmm Perhaps touch mylib.hpp or put `mylib.hpp` on `main.o: main.cpp mylib.hpp mylib.inl`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that the dependency described in your makefile:

```
mylib.hpp: mylib.inl
```

does not describe a real dependency. Changing `mylib.inl` does not change `mylib.hpp` (there is no rule to trigger such a change).

If `mylib.inl` is included from `mylib.hpp` then it should actually be a dependancy on `main.o` rather than `mylib.hpp`, leading to a dependency like this:

```
main.o: main.cpp mylib.hpp mylib.inl
```

Maintaining individual dependencies manually is likely to be error prone, which is why most compilers provide functions that can auto-create dependency files that you can include from your make file. You can then supply more generic rules for compilation. For more details on how to use this, check out [this article](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/).

Comment: Dang it, I was afraid of that. But thanks for the answer!

Comment: you could add a "touch mylib.hpp" as a rule for "mylib.hpp: mylib.inl"